# How can I paste a function parameter to be a string that have apostrophes inside of it

Tags: javascript, html

I have the `function delete()`:

```
var array = new Array();
function deleteMessage(name, role, date, time,text)  {
    alert(text);
}

var message = array[i].message.replace(/'/g,"\\'");
```

And the `input`

```
<input id='delete' name='delete' type='submit' value='Delete' onclick='deleteMessage(\""+ array[i].name + "\",\""+ array[i].role + "\",\""+ array[i].date + "\",\""+ array[i].time + "\",\""+ message +"\")'>
```

How can my function last parameter `text` get a string that has inside of it some single quotes.
I tried replacing with `.replace(/'/g,"\'");` , `.replace(/'/g,"\\'");`  , `.replace(/'/g,"\\`'");
And I tried replacing in the string like this `"It\'s my life"`

Nothing works, someone know how to do it?

Comment: Wouldn't have any of this problem if you stop using inline `onclick` and use more modern `Element.addEventListener` approach

Comment: all events pass the event as the first parameter.